# How can I make a random response in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

The title explains it I guess. I have no code written down and it would be nice if someone explains the steps to the code. I want it to send a random link for a wallpaper from a website each time the command 'a wallpaper' is used. Any helpers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.startsWith('!wallpaper')) {

// Here you can choose between creating your array with your own links or use a api that will generate it for you. For now i'll use an array

  const wallpapers = [
   'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/726436777283289088/734088186711769088/images.png',
   'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/726436777283289088/734088144730718258/images.png',
   'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/726436777283289088/734087421918183484/images.png',
   // You can add as many as you want
  ];
  // Here we will create a random number. Math.random only creates a randomly generated number between 0 and 1.
  const response = wallpapers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wallpapers.length)];
  message.reply(response);
 }
});
```

If you'd like, you can see more information about randomization in [w3school / Randomization](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing the responses you want to send. Then, you can use [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to get a random number between 0 and 1 (1 inclusive) and [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to get the index ranging from 0 to arrayLength - 1.

```js
const Responses = [
    "image 1",
    "image 2",
    "image 3",
    "image 4",
    "image 5"
];

const Response = Math.floor(Math.random() * Responses.length);

console.log(Responses[Response])
```

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    if (!message.guild) return false;
    if (message.content.indexOf(Prefix) !== 0) return false;

    const arguments = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(/ +/g); // Splitting the message.content into an Array with the arguments.
    // Input --> !test hello
    // Output --> ["test", "hello"]

    const command = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();
    // Removing the first element from arguments since it's the command, and storing it in a variable.

    if (command == "random") {
        const Response = Math.floor(Math.random() * Responses.length);
        message.channel.send(`Here is your random response: ${Responses[Response]}`);
    };
});
```

Comment: but how would the bot know which command to answer to. thats the thing thats been confusing me in every article i see

Comment: Isn't that only one response though? Also I'm so sorry. Excuse my ignorance in this topic

Comment: No. A response is generated each time the command is ran, because we are randomizing an item from the `Responses` array in the `Client#message` event.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I'll be marking the answer

Comment: Do you have any idea why it keeps selecting the same images every time?