# Discord Bot random replies do commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have no clue how to make the bot give out a random response. My commands will have at least 6 random responses and as I said, I have no clue how to code it. I haven't tried anything yet.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'random',
    description: "random responses",
    execute(message, args) {
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a random response in Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894234/how-can-i-make-a-random-response-in-discord-js)

Comment: You need to research and attempt your goal before asking for help

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want to respond anything?
You could call `Math.random()` function, get any number, stringify and just `message.reply(x)` where `x` is your random number.

Also you could use `random-text-generator` module from npm and for example reply with american city or something like: New York, Los Angeles etc. You only need to install this module.

Remember to call random function every time like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'random',
    description: "random responses",
    execute(message, args) {
    message.reply(Math.random().toString());
    }
}
```

If you want random response from array like:
`cities=["New York","Los Angeles","Chicago","Houston","Phoenix","Philadelphia","San Antonio"]`

You could do this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'random',
    description: "random responses",
    execute(message, args) {
    let cities=["New York","Los Angeles","Chicago","Houston","Phoenix","Philadelphia","San Antonio"]
    let randomNbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    message.reply(cities[randomNbr]);
    }
}
```