# How do I make my discord bot reply to a specific message with reply from a pool of replies?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Pretty much all in the title. I want my bot to respond with a random reply from a pool of replies. This is what I have so far:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Just Chillin');
    bot.user.setActivity('Working' , { type: 'BotOn'}).catch(console.error);

}); 

function randomMessage(){
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*2); // 0, 1 or 2
    switch(randomNumber){
        case 0: return 'Hello!';
        case 1: return 'Hi!';
        case 2: return 'Hola';
    }
}

bot.on('message' , message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('ping'))
        message.reply('pong')
    else if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('Hello'))
            message.reply(randomMessage());
});
```

Also, I do not have much experience in Java, only R, so I was also wondering where you would put the first chunk of code. Would you put it below or above the `bot.on('message', message=>`? Also, when I have that code entered, nothing happens and everything else runs fine.

Thank you in advance. I apologize for my lack of Java knowledge.

Comment: Please could you provide a minimum working example?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Could you elaborate on what you mean by a "working example?"

Comment: A minimum working example is basically just giving the community enough code to reproduce your project in their own environment, without divulging too much code, and without us (the community) having to guess on the specifics.

Comment: Sure, I will update it momentarily.

Comment: Maybe just try changing the `else if` to just: `else` ?

Comment: That worked!! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Please mark my comment(s) up and close the question :)

Comment: Do have another slight problem actually. When someone says "hello"
 it will work perfectly and gives a random response. But if i say ping, it will reply with pong and a random response. Any clue as to why it may be doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a random response in Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894234/how-can-i-make-a-random-response-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

When I want pick a random message (like 8ball), I always do it this way:

**Define different options:**

```js
let options = ["Hey", "Hello there!", "Hey, it's me!", "NOT NOW IM BUSY"];
```

**Pick a random message:**

```js
let result = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
```

**Log the result:**

```js
console.log(result);
```